# Nextjs13 dev server doesn't run, gives 404

Tags: node.js, next.js

So this happened to me once this morning earlier, and I thought it was associated with just deploying to AWS Amplify because it was failing to build, but then I realized that my dev server had randomly stopped working as well.

What I did to fix it was completely delete the project and start fresh and re-add the code piece by piece and make sure it worked.  It did the trick, thought maybe it was just something got randomly corrupted or something, but after a couple more hours of writing code it just happened again.  I restarted the dev server to just reflect the changes I had made by adding a color to my tailwind config, and when I restarted, I am getting the 404 again.  I tried to push what I have and AWS Amplify failed to build as well.

When I run `npm run dev`, the dev server in the terminal fires up as normal, and looks like this:

```
npm run dev

> kruegerandco@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
- event compiled client and server successfully in 352 ms (20 modules)
- wait compiling...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 167 ms (20 modules)
```

I go to open it in my browser and I get the generic Nextjs 404 page.

In the console I get:  `GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)` error and nothing else.

In the AWS Amplify build logs, I get this error:

```
2023-07-09T18:15:20.238Z [WARNING]: > Build error occurred
2023-07-09T18:15:20.239Z [WARNING]: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/codebuild/output/src127452464/src/kruegerandco/.next/server/app'] {
                                    errno: -2,
                                    code: 'ENOENT',
                                    syscall: 'lstat',
                                    path: '/codebuild/output/src127452464/src/kruegerandco/.next/server/app'
                                    }
2023-07-09T18:15:20.270Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
```

There is no .next/server/app in my folder structure, the app folder is in my src directory and was put there by default.

If someone can please help me figure this out so that it doesn't keep happening to me randomly it would be great.  Btw, this is my first project using app router so perhaps there is something associated to that, but I really have no idea.

EDIT:  I'm not sure if this is relevant but the error in the console is taking place at `on-demand-entries-client.js:49     GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just encountered the same issue after installing `shadcn/ui`. This particular library binds itself to the `globals.css` stylesheet.

During installation you are prompted to point the location the location of the file.

[screenshot of shadcn ui's installation prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MB3r.png)

This path is not actually where my `globals` file is. I am using the `src` folder, which means the path is actually `src/app/globals.css`. After banging my head against the wall I noticed that, after not finding the file, the script created an `app` folder in the root of the project.

I reinstalled/reinitialized the library, now pointing to the right folder, and the error is gone. I presume the error was happening because Next found the `app` folder in the root and tried to run the app from there.

My advice is to review your folder structure and see if Next isn't picking up something else. If you don't find anything, try to create a middleware function, if you don't have one. In that function, print something to the console. If you try access a route and get nothing on the console, it means the request is not even entering your app.

Create a `middleware.ts` file in your `app` folder (assuming you're using TypeScript and app router) and add the code below:

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("request", request);
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

When you try to access anything in the app (e.g., `localhost:3000`) this function should run and print the request on the development console, not the browser console.

If you're not able to fix the issue by reviewing the files, the function above will at least give you a hint about where the problem is.

Good luck!

Comment: This was it!  Good catch!  Works great and was successfully able to deploy to Amplify after the change as well.

Comment: Saved me by big time. Exactly went through the same issue