# Having trouble deploying nextjs app on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, next.js13

So I've been having a good deal of trouble trying to get my app deployed on AWS Amplify.

It currently fails on the frontend section of the build process.

Some info:

```
**next.config.js**
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

```
.eslintrc.json

{
  "extends": ["next/babel","next/core-web-vitals"]
}
```

```
package.json
{
  "name": "kruegerandco",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/node": "20.4.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.6",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.6.1",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "eslint": "8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.9",
    "hamburger-react": "^2.5.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.259.0",
    "next": "13.4.9",
    "postcss": "8.4.25",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.13.2",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.6",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  }
}
```

Here is the error from the deploy logs in Amplify:

```
2023-07-10T11:45:25.246Z [WARNING]: 
2023-07-10T11:45:25.247Z [WARNING]: > Build error occurred
2023-07-10T11:45:25.249Z [WARNING]: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/codebuild/output/src923177214/src/kruegerandco/.next/server/app'] {
                                    errno: -2,
                                    code: 'ENOENT',
                                    syscall: 'lstat',
                                    path: '/codebuild/output/src923177214/src/kruegerandco/.next/server/app'
                                    }
2023-07-10T11:45:25.282Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-07-10T11:45:25.282Z [INFO]: Please check the supported SSR features to find if your build failure is related to an unsupported feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ssr-Amplify-support.html#supported-unsupported-features. You may also find this troubleshooting guide useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssr-deployment.html
2023-07-10T11:45:25.283Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-07-10T11:45:25.283Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-07-10T11:45:25.283Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
```

It shows that its looking for a .next/server/app, but I have a pages folder present.

[image: file structure of .next folder]

and here if my amplify.yml:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Please help me resolve this frustrating issue!  Thanks!

Comment: Resolved, was due to shadcn/ui library. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76648957/nextjs13-dev-server-doesnt-run-gives-404

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by adding to the build app in amplify to use the last version of next and node js docker image version 18 as minimum.
I had a lot of trouble with amplify and I'm still working on it.
By default Amplify use node 16 and this makes some trouble with the latest version of next Js.